# IPC without unintentionally access

Tags: c++, linux, ipc

I am searching a way for my application, under a GNU/Linux-distribution, written in C++, to have an IPC.

My programm uses
3 libraries (Lib_A, Lib_B, Lib_C)
In Lib_A I run several forks() to allow separated, userdefined programms to use my programm.
These programms include Lib_B, Lib_C, whereby Lib_B, Lib_C offers functions, like an API, and in those functions should be a "translator" from function to IPC.

Lib_B is specially for the programm, as, if you want so, a system-API.
Lib_C is for XLib-windows.

Whereby I want to have an explicit, foreign untouchable connection between each process and Lib_A.
If e.g. Programm_A wants to communicate with Programm_B, it has to be over Lib_A (Lib_B, Lib_C).

Til now I tried several possibilies:
Message Queue > here is the problem, that a programm can call msgrcv() with msg_type = 0, which "destroys" my programm.

std-pipe > is also able to be captured

named-pipe > here I do not know, if it is fast enough, in respect to the messagequeue of XLib-windows (espacially MouseMove)

This I hadn't tried til now:
DBus > that is heavy! Beginning with, which library! I think, I would prefer libdbus-c++-dev, because I want to hold my programm "on one line", but I do not really know.

Can you please have a piece of advice, what would be the best way for my programm to have an IPC?

TIA 
Earlybite

Comment: I lost you at "foreign untouchable connection".

Comment: I think I do not exactly know what you mean. E.g. a MessageQuue allows to tap all messages from anywhere by msgq_id and msg_type = 0. I want to have an IPC with a dffinite key between Lib_A and an external programm, where is no possibility for another programm to read, or write in that foreign IPC.

Comment: So your problem is just restricting access to the inter process communication mechanism(e.g. message queue) to a set of processes?

Comment: Maybe this is a language issue but I really don't understand the question.  If you are forking these processes then you can use a pipe (assuming that meets your needs) and no foreign entity should even know.  For everything else, at a minimum, there are file permissions.  Put your users in a group and/or use ACL controls.  It's what the rest of the world manages to get by with.

Comment: @HAL: I think, that is corrrect? An IPC between e.g. Lib_A and e.g. a Program_A has to be possible only between Lib_A and Program_A, if Program_A want to communicate with Program_B, it first has to communicate with Lib_A...not only for a permission...always. That is the way I want IPC in my program. So again, yes, I think that is correct.

Comment: @Duc: I cannot set a new (e.g. Linux-Mint) user for each fork..., if I understood correctly.